# Infinite scrolling webpage

Tags: javascript

What I want to achieve is once the user scrolls to the bottom of the last div ("bottom") essentially the bottom of the webpage, they can keep scrolling down and the first div ("top") will appear from the bottom resetting the scrolling from the top
Ideally this would work both ways essentially creating infinite scrolling up and down

Any suggestions on what this is called or other information would be much appreciated, thank you

```
<div class="top">
<img>
</div>

<div>
<img>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
<img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way to do this, but I am thinking you can move the div once it passes the view port. Depending if you are scrolling up and down you pretty much can calculate where to move the divs. It is like a chain game, once you passed the element move it to the bottom or top. Or if it is already in the bottom, then move the last element to the top an so on. This is just an idea, so not sure if it will work with what you want to do.

Simple/rough example [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYyJEr)

HTML

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="top">
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
  </div>
  <div id="center">
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none;
}

#top {
  height: 1250px;
  background: blue;
}

#middle {
  height: 1250px;
  background: red;
}

#center {
  height: 1250px;
  background: pink;
}

#bottom {
  height: 1250px;
  background: green;
}
```

JS to check is user is scrolling up or down and to check if element is in the view port.

```
var divs = ['#top', '#middle', '#center', '#bottom'];

var current = '#top';
var next = '#center';

$('#body').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 ) {
    // Scrolling down
    if(!inScreen(current) && inScreen(next)) {
      $('#body').append($(current));
      current = divs[getNextIndex(current)];
      next = divs[getNextIndex(next)];
    }
  } else { // Scrolling up
    if(!inScreen(divs[getNextIndex(current)]) && inScreen(current)) {
      $('#body').prepend($(divs[getPrevIndex(current)]));
      current = divs[getPrevIndex(current)];
    }
  }
});

// Function to check if element is in view port
var inScreen = function (elem) {
  let elem_top = $(elem).offset().top;
  let elem_bottom = elem_top + $(elem).outerHeight();
  let window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  let window_bottom = window_top + $(window).height();

  return elem_bottom > window_top && elem_top < window_bottom;
};

// Function to get next index if last index then get the first one
var getNextIndex = function (item) {
  let idx = divs.findIndex(divs => divs === item);

  if((divs.length - 1) == idx) {
    idx = 0;
  } else {
    idx++;
  }

  return idx;
}

// Function to get previous index if first index then get the last one
var getPrevIndex = function (item) {
  let idx = divs.findIndex(divs => divs === item);

  if(0 == idx) {
    idx = divs.length - 1;
  } else {
    idx--;
  }
  return idx;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this code doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Sasha.Burger Do you mean the pen? Or the code does not work in your case?

Comment: That works perfectly! thank you. Would it be possible to add other divs in between the #top and the #bottom div id's that function in the same way?

Comment: Yeah, but thats where you will need to do some logic to append the div at the bottom or at the top. For instance, if you scrolling down move the div that you just past to the bottom. However, if you suddenly scroll up then the last div should be append to top.

Comment: Sorry if this is too much to ask but would you mind posting an example pen? I'm just not entirely sure how to make this work

Comment: @glittergirl I updated my answer and the pen. I did not test it thoroughly and I am sure the code can be refractor, but should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, as the user gets to the bottom div (end of the page), you don't want the page to rollback to top, right?
You want the top div to be rendered again right after the bottom div, correct?

You can use the **onscroll event on window** to check if the user hits the bottom and dinamically render the top div again.

Hope that helps.